# Customization of validation XML file names in Struts2

Tags: struts2, struts-validation

Is there any possibility that we can give customized names for `validation XMLs` in `Struts2`.

Generally If our action class name is `TestAction` then validation XML name should be `TestAction-actionName-validation.xml` or `TestAction-validation.xml`.

But I want give validation in an XML like Abc.xml. Is it possible?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: Hmm actually I am trainer. There might be a chance that one of my participants might ask whether it is possible or not? Because the file names are so attached to ActionClass name and xml file names are so lengthy because we have to follow convenstions.

Comment: @Jagadeesh The last thing is important, if you don't follow it, then you are on the way to abandon it, that leads in most cases to inappropriate behavior unless you provide your own implementation.